# Windows fopen and the N flag

Tags: windows, fopen

I'm reading some code that uses `fopen` to open files for writing. The code needs to be able to close and rename these files from time to time (it's a rotating file logger). The author says that for this to happen the child processes must not inherit these `FILE` handles. (On Windows, that is; on Unix it's OK.) So the author writes a special subroutine that duplicates the handle as non-inheritable and closes the original handle:

```
if (!(log->file = fopen(log->path, mode)))
    return ERROR;
#ifdef _WIN32
sf = _fileno(log->file);
sh = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(sf);
if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), sh, GetCurrentProcess(),
        &th, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)) {
    fclose(log->file);
    return ERROR;
}
fclose(log->file);
flags = (*mode == 'a') ? _O_APPEND : 0;
tf = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)th, _O_TEXT | flags);
if (!(log->file = _fdopen(tf, "at"))) {
    _close(tf);
    return ERROR;
}
#endif
```

Now, I'm  also reading [MSDN docs on `fopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e868993f-738c-4920-b5e4-d8f2f41f933d%28v=vs.90%29) and see that their version of `fopen` has a Microsoft-specific flag that seems to do the same: the `N` flag:

> N: Specifies that the file is not inherited by child processes.

Question: do I understand it correctly that I can get rid of that piece above and replace it (on Windows) with an additional `N` in the `mode` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

`fopen("myfile", "rbN")` creates a non-inheritable file handle.

The `N` flag is not mentioned anywhere in Linux documentation for `fopen`, so the solution will be most probably not portable, but for MS VC it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation; yes, I made sure to only use this extra flag on Windows.

Comment: Can anyone comment on whether Windows `N` is roughly equivalent to glibc's `e` (which corresponds to POSIX `O_CLOEXEC`)? Do they solve basically the same problem?